# Trimming numpy arrays: what is the best method?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, trim

Consider the following code:

```
a = np.arange (1,6)
b = np.array(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
c = np.arange (21, 26)

a,b,c =   a[a> 3],b[a>3], c[a >3]
print a,b,c
```

The output is: [4 5] ['D' 'E'] [24 25]

I cant' figure out why this output is different from the following:

```
a = np.arange (1,6)
b = np.array(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
c = np.arange (21, 26)

a = a[a>3]
b = b[a>3]
c = c[a>3]
print a,b,c
```

output: 
    [4 5] ['A' 'B'] [21 22]

Any idea?

Comment: Show us the results.  We can guess at what's happening, and even copy-n-paste (you are better than most), but still, it would be better if we can read the results directly.

Answer (score 2):

In the first part, when you do:

```
a, b, c = a[a> 3], b[a>3], c[a >3]
```

it is done over `a = np.arange (1,6)` - The value of `a` is only modified after all operations have been executed.

whereas in the second part, you are filtering `b` and `c` over an already filtered and modified `array a`, because it happens after you have done:

```
a = a[a>3]
```

Therefore, the following lines are filtered against array a now equal to `[4, 5]`

```
b = b[a>3]  # <-- over a = [4, 5] gives values at index 0 and 1
c = c[a>3]  # <-- over a = [4, 5] gives values at index 0 and 1
```

*In the second case, you could use a temporary array to hold the filtered values of a.*

```
temp = a[a>3]
b = b[a>3]
c = c[a>3]
a = temp
```

or, as suggested in the comments by @hpaulj, evaluate and store the mask in a variable first, then use it as many times as needed without having to redo the work:

```
mask = a > 3 
a = a[mask]
b = b[mask]
c = c[~mask]
```

Comment: This is what I suspected. By curiosity: to filter all initial numpy arrays over a>3, is the first code the most efficient and "proper" method?

Comment: Yes, the first code is the recommended way to do it in python. I am confident this is also the proper way with numpy.

Comment: I find the syntax a bit misleading. A begginner might believe that the first code actually implements the second. This is actually the mistake that a friend (that starts learning python) did.

Comment: The first syntax is often demonstrated with an expression like `a,b = b,a` as a means interchanging values.  Actually I prefer to put the mask in a temporary variable.  That way it is evaluated only once and there's less confusion: `mask=a>3; a=a[mask]; b=b[mask]; c=c[~mask]`.

Comment: Good suggestion @hpaulj

Comment: Very good advice @hpauly. Thank you guys, I've improved my python skills today.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix is to **trim your "a" array last, not first**!

```
b=b[a>3]
c=c[a>3]
a=a[a>3]
```

If you plan to perform multiple trimmings, then consider saving the [a>3] to a variable temporarily (as instructed by other answer) which may help improve computational efficiency.

Comment: Hi Brian! Please provide code in your answer. You also might want to check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer